# Retrieve wordpress REST current user in nextjs app

Tags: wordpress, next.js, axios, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using the JWT Authentication for WP-API plugin to generate the token.
User crendetials are submitted to `/jwt-auth/v1/token` endpoint then store token to cookie then `setState` as follow

```js
setAuth({ status: 'SIGNED_IN', user: response.data.user_display_name});
```

then on restricted page I check if user is valid from `getServerSideProps`

```js
export const authenticateUser = async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/wp/v2/users/me`, {}, { 
      headers: { 
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });
    // if is it returns the right informations
    return { status: 'SIGNED_IN', user: response.data.user}
    // else
    return { status: 'SIGNED_OUT', user: null}
  }
}

export const getServerSideProps = async context => {
    // retrieve user
    const auth = await authenticateUser(context);
    console.log(auth);
    // if there is no authenticated user, redirect to homepage
    if (auth.status === 'SIGNED_OUT') {
        return {
            props: {},
            redirect: { destination: "/" },
        }
    }

    return { props: { user: auth.user } }
}
```

In postman the requests are working fine using the right authorization bearer token.

But in my nextjs app I have the following response

```js
{
  code: 'rest_not_logged_in',
  message: 'Vous n’êtes actuellement pas connecté.',
  data: { status: 401 }
}
```

I also tried to check if user id exists using

```js
const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/wp/v2/users/${userId}`, {}, { 
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
  }
});
```

but I have the following response

```js
{
  code: 'rest_user_cannot_view',
  message: 'Désolé, vous n’avez pas l’autorisation de lister les comptes.',
  data: { status: 401 }
}
```

Any help will be appreciate.

**EDIT**

It appears that the problem come from axios, fetch API works great.

Comment: When using `axios.get` the options object should be passed as the second parameter, e.g. ``axios.get('<url>', { headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` } })``.